# Efficient way to handle post requests on Java Vert.x?

Tags: java, post, vert.x

This is how I am currently handling post requests on my vert.x server:

```
router.post("/test").handler(context -> context.request().bodyHandler(body -> {
    try {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(body.toString());
        ... 
    } catch(Exception e) { }
}));
```

I am sending test requests using Postman where the body has data as "raw - application/json".

This works. But, is this the right way?

I also tried sending the data as parameters in "form-data" but I am not able to get the parameters. The following prints out the entire request, I can see the data, but cannot parse it to a json or map.

```
router.post("/test").handler(context -> 
    context.request().bodyHandler(System.out::println));
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you can program you request handlers.
You can find different approaches in this documentation https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/

Here is an approach I prefer when writing my handlers.

```
package org.api.services.test;

import org.api.services.test.CustomDTO;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.json.Json;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.BodyHandler;

public class TestApi extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
        super.start(startFuture);

        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

        //register a router for post request that accepts only requests with */json MIME type on exact path /test.
        router.post("/test/").consumes("*/json").handler(this::testHandler);
        ...
    }

    private void testHandler(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        //recommended way to extract json
        JsonObject jsonObject = routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
        //automatically map json to custom object
        CustomDTO customDTO = Json.decodeValue(routingContext.getBodyAsString(), CustomDTO.class);
        ...
    }
}
```

If you are sending request containing form-data you can extract 2 ways:

1. If you add `router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());` than all form attributes will be merged as request parameters.

> By default, the body handler will merge any form attributes into the request parameters. If you don’t want this behaviour you can use disable it with setMergeFormAttributes.

You can extract them by using `routingContext.request().getParam("attribute_name")`

2. If you are not using any **BodyHandler** you need to set `routingContext.request().setExpectMultipart(true);` and than access the form attributes like this `routingContext.request().formAttributes()`

Answer (score 0):

If you need "form-data", you should add "BodyHandler" before your handle.

```
final Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
....
context.request().getParam("id")
```